# Disaable the prompts to save files

Tags: buffers

Every time, I save files, it prompts that

```
save files ..? (y, n !)
```

There are few cases that saving files are mistake operations.

How could disable the confirmation prompts?

Comment: What command are you using to save files?

Comment: Dear Algebra, my first approach had a catch (see the edited answer). I've corrected that. Please adopt the changes in your init file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you actually use [`save-some-buffers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Commands.html) bound to the key sequence <kbd>C-x s</kbd>.

EDIT:

My first suggestion to add `(setq-default buffer-save-without-query t)` to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) has a catch. Emacs tries to save also modfied non-file buffers with this setting and you are asked to input file names for such buffers.

It is better to keep the default value `nil` of `buffer-save-without-query` and to change the buffer local value in file buffers to t:

```el
(defun set-buffer-save-without-query ()
  "Set `buffer-save-without-query' to t."
  (unless (variable-binding-locus 'buffer-save-without-query)
    (setq buffer-save-without-query t)))

(add-hook #'find-file-hook #'set-buffer-save-without-query)

;; The following avoids being ask to allow the file local
;; setting of `buffer-save-without-query'.
;; IMHO it is not a big risk:
;; The malicious code that must not be saved
;; should never be allowed to enter Emacs in the first place.
(put 'buffer-save-without-query 'safe-local-variable #'booleanp)
```

The doc string of `buffer-save-without-query` says:

> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
>
> Non-nil means `save-some-buffers' should save this buffer without asking.

If you have some buffer for which saving accidently is desastrous you can buffer-locally set `buffer-save-without-query` to nil. Your changes are not overwritten by `set-buffer-save-without-query`.

You can set `buffer-save-without-query` with file-local variables or in some mode hook.

Example for file-local settings:
Add the following lines at the end of the file (you can also comment them out if that is important):

```
Local Variables:
buffer-save-without-query: nil
End:
```

Example for a mode hook:

```el
(defun my-query-when-save ()
  "Set `buffer-save-without-query' to nil for this buffer."
  (setq buffer-save-without-query nil))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'my-query-when-save)
```